# Can iPad 3 play 2048×1536 video in its native resolution?

Tags: video, ipad, resolution

Can the third generation iPad play 2048×1536 videos in its native resolution?

I've converted some 4K footage to 2048×1536 mp4s using Apple Compressor. These files play correctly on my Mac, but iTunes refuses to sync them over to my iPad.

How can I achieve 1:1 pixel perfect Post-HD videos on my iPad 3?

Comment: Can you post a sample video? Maybe someone else can get it to work

Comment: This [forum thread](http://www.edavs.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=11135&sid=6f001f5b6dbe5e1494adc40ebdd17c90) seems to indicate that [OPlayer](http://www.edavs.com/OPlayer.shtml) will support Retina resolution. Posting as a comment since I'm not sure support is there, yet.

Comment: Sample video: download this one, then convert it to the target resolution yourself: http://reduser.net/forum/showthread.php?68200-Tom-Lowe-TimeScapes-4k

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at [this page,](http://www.reduser.net/forum/showthread.php?75085-quot-new-Ipad-quot-%283%29-how-do-I-get-highest-quality-demo-video-on-it&p=973240&viewfull=1#post973240)  it looks like the guy figured out how to get to 1920x1440 and even up to 2048x1536 using mpeg4 or h264.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no.  The following lists the available format for displaying video output on the device:

**Video formats supported**:

- H.264 video up to 1080p, 30 frames per second, High Profile level 4.1 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
- MPEG-4 video up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps per channel, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
- Motion JPEG (M-JPEG) up to 35 Mbps, 1280 by 720 pixels, 30 frames per second, audio in ulaw, PCM stereo audio in .avi file format

So the maximum resolution is 1080p (1920 x 1080), there is no way to displayer higher, and certainly not native *through the default media playing apps at least*.  3rd party apps may well allow for this if they include a suitable codec, but I am not aware of any that do.

Answer (score -2):

If you have an Apple developer account, you could copile your own [VLC media](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html) player.